# Different code execution on different times events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

I have to show complete **24 hours cycle** in Unity3d Scene. **Where different kind of task will be executed in different Times.**

Suppose

- at 2pm I have to move a car,
- at 6pm An Aeroplane will land on airport
- at 07:07pm I have to open the door of Market's Buildings
- and so on different task/works execution at different timing.

Now, I have some basic animation e.g., car, Aeroplane and door etc.,. Now I am confuse that how to play and stop **my animation according to the time**. And time can also be
changed manually using GUI. If currently 6pm (animation working) then user can switch to 8am to view 8am time's animation. And User can also fast the timing to view complete hours in a single minutes or in an hour.

I can use **if/else** in **Update Events** but I guess this is not the **right way** to do and will be **very difficult** if I require to show significant number of works
in different time duration (which means significant number of if/else statements).  Just like below

```
void Update(){
if(time =1){
//logic 
}
if(time =2){
//logic 
}
if(time =3){
//logic 
}
...//so on, tedious way 
...//and also not possible if time require between the hours, suppose 06:06pm
}
```

What to do ? How to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. if statements are the most unprofessional. I would recommend you to use UnityEvents in this situation.

Let's say I need to trigger stuff at x:00 times. I would create an array of UnityEvents of size 24 and trigger 1 per hour. like this:

```
public UnityEvent[] hourTrigger;    //24 hours
public float oneHour = 120f;        //one hour in game is 120 seconds real time
private int hourCounter = 0;

void Start(){
    hourTrigger = new UnityEvent[24];
    StartCoroutine (HourlyTrigger ());
}

IEnumerator HourlyTrigger(){

    //repeat this every oneHour interval
    while(true){
        hourTrigger[hourCounter].Invoke();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(oneHour);

        hourCounter = ++hourCounter % 24;
    }

}
```

Then you can add listeners to any of the triggers and they will automatically get started at appropriate times.

This is just off the top of my head, most probably someone else will post a better solution. Still, one big advantage of this code is that you write this and you will never have to open this script ever again. You can add your scheduled actions and remove them from outside scripts.

Comment: Why do you say: `if statements are the most unprofessional`?

Comment: because, well, I think I can weakly reference [OOP Message Passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Dynamic_dispatch.2Fmessage_passing) on this one - "it is the responsibility of the object, not the external code, to 'on-demand' select the procedural code to run/execute in response to a method call". In your case the time manager class is the "external code" which invokes your methods. It's good to have non-hardcoded method calls to maintain freedom of renaming, adding and removing methods to be called. Also, if statements always result in huge code.

Comment: I think he meant in this situation where you end up with 24 if statement. He could have also mentioned switch which would result in the same. Using delegate allows to do it in no more than 5 lines.

Comment: so basically what I'm saying is, it is not the responsibility of your time manager script to manage all the things - it's a huge mess and totally against OOP. In OOP one class does one thing. It is the responsibility of other classes to use your time manager, not other way around.

Comment: The only downside of this approach I could see is the fact that it can only take one method per hour.  Maybe a better approach would be to have an array of array of delegate (jagged array). Each hour iterates through the collection of methods.

Comment: @NikaKasradze where are the events?

Comment: @NikaKasradze i am getting null refrence error. although i have add this  hourTrigger[0].AddListener(FirstHour); public void FirstHour() {
        Debug.Log("First Hour Function exectued");
    }

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it is code design issue. I recommend to use some kind of Observer pattern. You need to subscribe `IObersver` objects in main controller which will trigger all subscribers on some events, for example each minute, like this:

```
foreach(IObserver observer in observers) {
   observer.Notify();
}
```

Each observer will check time using it's own schedule. For instance, traffic light observer will check if 1 minute passed from last switch and if yes, then switch light:

```
public TrafficLight : IObserver {
   ...

  public void Notify() {
     if(timePassed > sachedulledTime) {
        SwithcLight();
     }
  }
```

Using this code design you can add to your controller as many object as you need without even knowing which these objects are and what is their schedule.